# python pandas datetime datetime does not work well

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have tried to solve this problem with a lot of methods but none of them worked.

I would like to convert a `pandas` series to `datetime`.

I think I may have miss some small but important part.

```
print test["order_date"][3]
print type(test["order_date"][3])

test["order_date"] = pd.to_datetime(test["order_date"], format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

##have also tried 
##test["order_date"] = pd.to_datetime(test["order_date"], infer_datetime_format=True) 
##test["order_date"] = test["order_date"].apply(pd.to_datetime)
##all turn out to be the same result

print test["order_date"][3]
print type(test["order_date"][3])
```

The outcome turns out to be like below:

```
20150731000001
<type 'numpy.int64'>

1970-01-01 05:35:50.731000001 
<class 'pandas.tslib.Timestamp'>
```

I cannot figure out why the `result` becomes `1970-01-01`

*If any further information is needed please kindly let me know.*

Thanks!

Comment: Wrong format, so the number 20150731000001 is interpreted as ms since 1970 - which corresponds to your result.

Answer (score 4):

You have specified a wrong format.

Try this:

```
In [34]: pd.to_datetime(['20150731000001'], format="%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
Out[34]: DatetimeIndex(['2015-07-31 00:00:01'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

Comment: @LeighTsai, glad it helps :)

Answer (score 2):

It's because the dtype is `int64` so it assumes nanosecond unit value:

```
In[51]:
pd.to_datetime(20150731000001, unit='ns')
Out[51]: Timestamp('1970-01-01 05:35:50.731000001')
```

If it was a string then it would be able to parse correctly:

```
In[54]:
pd.to_datetime('20150731000001')
Out[53]: Timestamp('2015-07-31 00:00:01')
```

So you can either explicitly pass a format string (like in @MaxU's answer) or convert the dtype of the column to `str` and then pass this:

```
test["order_date"] = pd.to_datetime(test["order_date"].astype(str))
```